# How to check the mail has been sent in the gmail?

Tags: testng

How to check the mail has been sent in the gmail?

I have entered the mail id and sent the mail. It is giving me the line the mail has been sent. How to verify that?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add a unique identifier to the subject. Open the send mail screen (by clicking the button in the left menu) and check the item is in there.

If looking in the "send mail" screen is not enough, because you want to verify the mail is received by the other end. Then have a look at a service like [Mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io/). You can send emails to their account, they catch the mail and then you can use the [API](http://docs.mailtrap.apiary.io/) with which you can programmatically check the mail is received correctly. Mailtrap has a free tier, which should be sufficient for testing small amounts of email.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  MailTrack for Gmail  to check the mail has been sent or not.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailtrack-for-gmail/ndnaehgpjlnokgebbaldlmgkapkpjkkb/related?hl=en

And also http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/track-opened-gmail/.

Answer (score 0):

I addressed this with a small webapp that uses [JavaMail](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) API to talk to Google's mail service over [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol).  The webapp supports URLs like the following:

```
/inbox/username=xxx&password=xxx
```

This returns metadata (e.g. subject line, message number, recipient, received date) about the most recent 20 messages.

```
/message/username=xxx&password=xxx&id=xxx
```

This returns the body of the specified message.

```
/attachment/username=xxx&password=xxx&id=xxx&attachmentId=xxx
```

This returns the specified attachment of the specified message.

Our QA staff use Selenium, so the output is formatted in HTML with lots of element IDs and element classes.  Of course you could could just as easily return XML or something like JSON or YAML.